# Using anchors on a page with <base> set

Tags: html, anchor, base-url

If I set my base url like so:

```
<base href='http://example.com' />
```

And then put a link to an anchor on the page http://example.com/test.php:

```
<a href='#top'></a>
```

How do I make sure the anchor stays on the same page and goes to the link http://example.com/test.php#top as opposed to going to http://example.com/#top because it uses the base url?

Essentially, is there any way to specify that this particular link must be relative and not use the base?

Answer (score 2):

You could either do:

```
<base href='http://example.com' />
<a href='test.php#top'></a>
```

or

```
<base href='http://example.com/test.php' />
<a href='#top'></a>
```

I don't think there is any magic way that the client is going to know what file to use as part of the base if you don't define it.

Comment: I understood I could do any of these BUT the second one does not solve my problem because I want the base url to be http://example.com for all the other urls on the page. (Otherwise there wouldn't be any point of using a base in the first place.)

Comment: Essentially, is there any way to specify that this particular link must be relative and not use the base?